# What is the STL code for splice?

Tags: c++

In order to write my program I need the stl library to write my code but i can t for the life of me find the code to splice in STL format.

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::splice(List<T>::Iterator position,
  List<T>::Iterator start, List<T>::Iterator end) {

}
```

Comment: Uh, can you clarify? Your question is *way* to unclear. What do you mean by `splice`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at [`std::list::splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice)?

> Transfers elements from one list to another.
>   No elements are copied or moved, only the internal pointers of the list nodes are re-pointed. The behavior is undefined if: get_allocator() != other.get_allocator(). No iterators or references become invalidated, the iterators to moved elements remain valid, but now refer into *this, not into other.

Note that when splicing in a range, the time is linear, rather than O(1).